# Cordova Webview and Splashscreen dont work

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I installed Cordova plugin:

```
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Everything works fine with this plugin, but then I installed

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

for creating splashscreen. In file config.xml in widget section I put this code:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

Build was successful. After start application it shows splashscreen (for 5 second), but when splashscreen is disappear, it shows just white page instead my app. After I remove webview plugin - everyting works fine. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: will you get error logs in console?

Comment: Naitik, no, because I tested on device (not emulator), my CPU doesn't support some instructions for emulator.

Comment: you can check log in chrome with inspect, run your app in device and in google chrome go to :  chrome://inspect/#devices you can get your app page there just click on "inspect" to get app in debugg mode.

Comment: Naikit, thank you for good advice, now I test though "inspect". But logs has no errors (but app are started, system log record exists)

Comment: The problem is solved, there was a syntax error, thanks for help

Comment: Glad you solved your error... happy coading.